# Why can't I find elements on a page using GetElementById?

Tags: javascript, html, vba, dom, getelementbyid

Hello I am working on Internet Explorer automation solution using VBA. After inspecting my webpage and inspecting the element of interest to determine its ID. `IE.document.GetElementByID` method fails because the ID cannot be found. I should add that the webpage is dynamic. So I thought i should wait a bit to let the javascripts finish running. I halted the execution of the VBA code for 1 min, but that didn't help.

I have also assigned the content of `.body.innerHTML` and `.body.outerHTML` to a text file to inspect the content but that element was nowhere to be found. I also saved as a complete webpage and looked at the html file generated with a text editor but still that element (and many more) on the page were missing.

Edit: Sample Code Added

```
Sub Test_Login()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Navigate2 "http://www.example.com"
    Do
        If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
        ie.Visible = True
        Exit Do
        Else

        DoEvents
        End If
    Loop
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 20)
    ie.document.getElementById("commandSignIn").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: It's `getElementById` with an initial **lower-case** "g".

Comment: Yeah thanks but VBA is not case sensitive so that is not the issue

Comment: can you post an exact line of code?

Comment: Via internetexplorer.application? Are you waiting for readyState?

Comment: Wait, you said you inspected the actual html content of the body, and the element wasn't there.

So obviously the method will return nothing...

Comment: *<<that element (and many more) on the page were missing>>*

I think this answers your question. If the specified elements **do not exist** then the `getElementByID` method will (expectedly) return `Nothing`.  What else could it *possibly* return?

Comment: The element is there because I see I can see it with the DOM explorer in IE, however it is not showing in innerHTML, outerHTML, or in the HTML file generate when I save the webpage as a complete webpage

Comment: Without an URL or more/any HTML this is not an [MCVE] and it will be difficult for others to benefit from this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to get a handle on IE items:

```
IE.Document.All.Item("InputField")
```

To wait until the website is loaded:

```
Do Until Not .Busy
    ' nothing needed here
Loop
```

Full Code to Login to a Website from Internet Explorer

```
Private Sub LoginToWebsite()
    ' needs references to
    ' microsoft internet controls
    ' microsoft HTML object library

     ' Prepare to open the web page
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "www.WebsiteToLoginTo.com"

         '  Loop until the page is fully loaded
        Do Until Not .Busy
            ' nothing needed here
        Loop

         ' Make the desired selections on the web page and click the submit Button

        ' get handle on user name item and enter value
        Set webItem = IE.Document.all.Item("UserNameEntry")
        webItem.Value = "username"

        ' get handle on password item and enter value
        Set webItem = IE.Document.all.Item("PasswordEntry")
        webItem.Value = "password"

        ' get handle on submit button item and click
        Set webItem = IE.Document.all.Item("SubmitButton")
        webItem.Value = "submit"
        webItem.Click

         ' Loop until the page is fully loaded
        Do Until Not .Busy
            ' nothing needed here
        Loop         

    End With

End Sub
```